# How to encode "C\u9999" as %22C\u9999%22 with URL encoder

Tags: java, scala, url

The title pretty much sums it up.

I need to set a query param of `"C\u9999"` which should end up as `%22C\u9999%22`. Closest I've come is with `"C\\u9999"` which ends up as `%22C%25%5Cu9999%22` after the URLEncoder chews on it.

Edit

I'm trying to make a web service call against couchdb in which I'm setting the url as `contract?startkey="C"&endkey="C\u9999"` so I can do a partial key match. When I type this into my browser everything works fine and I can see in CouchDB's log the request url is `contract?startkey="C"&endkey="C\u9999"`. I am trying to replicate this programmatically.

Comment: I don't get what's the question. If you mean _what's the url-encoded version of "C\u9999"_ the answers is **%22C%5Cu9999%22**. FYI i used this website: [ONLINE URL ENCODER/DECODER](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: Is the \u9999 supposed to represent a unicode character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode escapes (the \u9999 part) are a method of single character representation in Java strings.  They allow you to enter in certain Unicode characters that might not be supported by your text editor (such as when you use a text editor that doesn't support UTF-8).

URLs / URIs do not use the same character representation scheme.  They use a series of %xy escape sequences, not `\uXXXX` escape sequences, so your string will always come out without the \u unicode escape sequence being preserved and never come out `%22C\u9999%22` because the `\u9999` part cannot be part of a valid URL.

When you choose to encode `\\u9999` you are *not* encoding a single Unicode character because you have double-escaped the initial `\` which means you actually encoded six characters instead of one, one `\` character, one `u` character and four `9` characters.

In any event, it is almost always better to actually use a UTF-8 supporting editor, and to figure out the way to actually type in the character in question without resorting to Java Unicode escape values.  It too will expand to something that lacks the Java string specific escape sequence because, URLs are not constructed according to the exact encoding rules of Java strings.  However, by using the UTF-8 supporting editor, you wouldn't be under the impression that the `\u9999` should be preserved; because, that representation won't be in the initial string in the first place (the actual unicode character will be there).

Comment: I've updated the description to expand on what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You are not trying to use a Java unicode escape sequence on the input side then,  use `\\Cu9999` because you really want 7 characters, not 1.  The `\\` will always come out in encoded form `percent something` to avoid its secondary role in most systems, that of an escape character specifying a special character interpretation mode.  If you can, ditch the range representation with one that steps on fewer toes, and rewrite the servlet side of things to construct the couchdb received query.  Picking the magic string that is valid in two worlds isn't always possible.